# JQuery Ajax call is taking much time

Tags: ajax

I am using JQuery ajax call which is perfectly running in local server. but when i deploy it on the actuall server. Ajax call is taking much time almost 1 second for every call [In some cases there is no data in return]. I am populating 5 dropdowns from Ajax call and it is taking 5 seconds which is very much. Please can anyone guide me towards the actuall solution. Thanks in Advanced.

Here is my code

```
function DropDownList() {  
    $.ajax({  
        data: '{}',  
        url: urlAddress + 'LoadDropDown',  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        async: false,  
        dataType: "json",  
        type: "POST"  
        success: OnSuccess,           
        error: OnError  
    });  
  }
```

Comment: Is the ajax page called taking longer to load if loaded in a separate window? I'd use something like firebug to find out. If so is the ajax page calling a database - and is it the same one as the localhost was using? I suspect the issue is not in the jquery code you're using but in the ajax content that is being loaded.

Comment: I checked the statastics of Ajax call from Fiddler. Its showing that the Request is taking most of the time and response takes only 10 miliseconds. How can i optimized Request. Where as Request takes only request header and two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The slow down maybe because of a number of reasons. It might be that the server is overloaded or that your internet bandwidth is slow. Since the response is fast on your local machine then slowdown is obviously not because of jQuery. 
check the response time in firebug's net tab. also check the data returned from the server. it might be that the data returned might be taking too much time to process in your success method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked out my request stats. Its showing 1 second to request and 1ms for response.

Comment: How can i optimized the request time for AJax. Is it a server side code problem or a server itself

Comment: @ITMount: I don't think there will be a need to optimize ajax call are your side cause the jQuery creators would have already done it. check the method that is called on success. optimize that. that method may be causing the problems. if the server is responding with 1ms(1ms?! are you sure?) then the problem must be with the success method. check loading of other data elsewhere in the application. if that is loading fast then the success function has to be optimized.

Comment: Is there any effect if i use Session object on server side, Like if i save value in Session and then return value at clientside

Comment: it will not have much effect.

Comment: I checked the statastics of Ajax call from Fiddler. Its showing that the Request is taking most of the time and response takes only 10 miliseconds. How can i optimized Request. Where as Request takes only request header and two arguments.

Comment: Is there a similar problem else where in the application too or just this particular instance? Is it still taking 1 sec per call? There is always some time time lapse for establishing a connection with the server but that is usually negligible if you have a good enough internet/LAN speed. Minify your JS to improve time. Minification can substantially improve performance. If the combos are used frequently consider caching the data. Also remove `async : false` if its not required. You're using asynchronous connections which will cause delays.

Comment: Also, if you're only requesting data from the server, then change type to GET. This will also marginally improve performance.

Answer (score -3):

```
please avoid using remote jquery server like
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

instead u can download from source and use it like 
<script src="JS/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

so only ajax and jquery functions and events will perform faster.
```

Comment: While this can be helpful for initial page load times since the script is loaded into the browser cache on first visit and used from there for future requests, this doesn't help at all for making AJAX calls that the original question asks.